# Encapsulating getting the method's name in a helper method

Tags: logging, kotlin, log4j2

For debugging purposes there's a part of my code in which I want to log the name of a method, like this:

```
val LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SomeClass::class.java.name)
//...
fun someMethod() {
   LOG.debug(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName())
```

How can I have this as a minimal but legible expression? Something like:

```
LOG.debug(getMethodName())
```

By the way, I tried using AspectJ for this but I'm using Eclipse and the Kotlin plugin works with 1.1.1. AspectJ would require KAPT (as far as I know) which doesn't work with maven (which I'm also using) for 1.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an extension function on Thread which gives you the first method on the stack:

```
fun Thread.firstStackMethod() = stackTrace[1].methodName
```

Call it like this then:

```
LOG.debug(Thread.currentThread().firstStackMethod())
```

Maybe it's even a good alternative for you to extend the Logger directly:

```
fun Logger.debugMethodName(t: Thread) = debug(t.stackTrace[1].methodName)
//use
LOG.debugMethodName(Thread.currentThread())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function at file level.

```
fun getMethodName(): String =
    Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[1].methodName

class Foo {
    ...
}
```

By adjusting the `stackTrace` number, you can get the level you want.